# When to remove object from display list

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a flash game that consists of many different screens (Login, Menu, Game, etc), with each screen having it's own background image.

For example, on a successful login I can execute:

```
addChild(new Menu());
```

This will create a menu ontop of the login screen and the login screen will no longer be visible. Similarly, if the user clicks on 'play' in the menu, I can call `addChild(new Game())` to initiate the game.

This would leave the display tree something like this I'm guessing

```
-Login page
  - Menu
    - Game
```

Should I be removing the previous screens from the display tree? For example, when the user clicks 'play' in the menu. Should I first `removeChild(menu)` before calling `addChild(new Game())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this obviously depends on the architecture of your game and how you manage the resources. As you tagged the question flash and not AIR, I'm going to assume that this game is for consumption using a web browser.

The first thing I would point out, is that it will be much easier to remove your items by creating a reference to them first:

```
var menu:Menu = new Menu();
addChild(menu);

// later
removeChild(menu);
```

What you need to do is balance the efficiency of maintaining objects over the cost of recreating them.

If you have an object which is doing a lot of calculations, then just doing removeChild may not be enough, often you have a destroy() method in a class to clean up the resources, then you recreate the object from scratch, thus allowing the garbage collector to manage the resources more effectively.

If your object like a menu in your example, does not do anything fancy then keeping it in memory and removing and re-attaching to the display list may be just fine.

I hope this helps you with your game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, otherwise you're wasting precious memory and CPU cycles, the benefit of removing unused screens definitely outweighs the benefits of just keeping all of the screens on the display list.